# Change CSS class of LinkButton in Repeater Itemcommand Event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to change CSS class of linkbutton which is inside repeater control,in repeater itemcommand event, I am using this code

```
 if (e.CommandName == "read")
                {
                    LinkButton btnread = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("cmdread");             
                     bool isread = true;
                    if (btnread.CssClass == "red-read")
                    {
                        isread = false;
                    }

                    if (isread)
                    {
                        btnread.CssClass = "";
                        btnread.CssClass = "red-read";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        btnread.CssClass = "";
                        btnread.CssClass = "grey-read";
                    }

                    }
```

but its not working, I also tried this code

```
if (isread )
                    {
                        btnread.CssClass = btnread.CssClass.Replace("grey-read","red-read");


                    }
                    else
                    {
                    btnread.CssClass = btnread.CssClass.Replace("read-read","grey-read");

                    }
```

How Can I change CSS class in code behind file
This is my repeater control

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptData" runat="server" DefaultItemsPerPage="15" ShowItemsPerPageOptions="true"
                         ShowPageControls="true"
                        PageControlsPlaceHolder="phFooterControls" NoResultsControl="lblNoResults" OnItemDataBound="rptData_ItemDataBound"
                        OnItemCommand="rptData_ItemCommand">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" class="datatable">
                                <tr>
                                   <th>Name</th>
                                   <th>Location</th>
                                   <th></th>
                                </tr>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>                               
                                <td>
                                    <%#Eval("Firstname")%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%#Eval("Location")%>
                                </td>                                                        
                               <td>                                                                 
                                  <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdread" runat="server" CssClass="red-read" CommandName="read"
                                        CommandArgument='<%#Eval(this.PKField) %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                     <td class="alt">
                                    <%#Eval("Firstname")%>
                                </td>
                                <td class="alt">
                                    <%#Eval("Location")%>
                                </td>                                                         
                               <td class="alt">
                                  <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdread" runat="server" CssClass="red-read" CommandName="read"
                                        CommandArgument='<%#Eval(this.PKField) %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="9" class="tablefooter">
                                    <div class="FloatLeft" style="width: 475px;">
                                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phFooterControls" runat="server" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="FloatRight" style="width: 90px; text-align: right;">
                                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phItemsPerPage" runat="server" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="FloatClear">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: The value IsFlag, where it is being set?

Comment: Dear @syed why are you not using jquery for it try to use jquery it will b much more easy for you

Comment: @unseendreamzzz Can you give me some sample code/Tutorial of using jquery with repeater?

Comment: Can you provide your HTML code?

Comment: Dear @syed if you like video tutorial then go to www.lynda.com or if you want to learn from the jquery site then go to the http://api.jquery.com/category/css/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this code. Replace you if condition to set `isread = false` with below code

```
if (btnread.CssClass.Equals("red-read",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
      isread = false;
}
```

Also command name condition with this

```
if (e.CommandName.Equals("read",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Let us know if still error persists or not?

Comment: if (btnread.CssClass == "red-read") this code is working fine, I have to change CSS class on the based on isread value, which is coming as per expected

Comment: I think the code may be working fine. But the problem is with CSS. It might be the case where CSS class or CSS style is not available on browser. Check wheterh CSS is registered or not? Try check the page source or firebug (in firefox) or developer tools (in IE). Also in your second code block spelling of "red-read" is "read-read"